# Laravel - Many-to-many relation, product count by product feature

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, many-to-many

Trying to get the count of products by its features(many-to-many)
For instance,

```
Product::with([’features’])->where(category_id, $category_id)->get();
```

Product A->feature1->id

/feature2->id

/feature3->id

Product B->feature3->id

/feature4->id

/feature6->id

.....

how could i get product count from each feature (after filtered by product category)

I am not good at explain in wording, tried my best.

Final result
feature 1 -> 19 products
feature 2 -> 5 products
...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do the trick

```
   with(['products' => function($q) use($category_id){
                    $q->where('category_id',18);
                }])

                ->find($feature_ids)

                ->groupBy('feature_type_id');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Select product_id from products where category_id = "'.$category_id.'" group by feature_id;
```

Comment: How could I groupBy feature->id? in product collection each product might have couple feature collections, so product->features->feature1->id, product->features->feature2->id, product->features->feature3->id

Comment: $product_features_with_count = Feature::
      with(['products'])
      // ->where('products.category_id', $id)
      ->whereHas('products', function($q) use($id){
       return $q->where('products.category_id', $id);
      })
      ->find($feature_ids)
      ->groupBy('feature_type_id');

Comment: I am almost there, but not collection doesn't query the category, it includes everything

Answer (score 0):

You should Define relation within your `Product` and `Feature` Model

```
class Product extends Model {
    public function features(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Feature::class);
    }
}

class Feature extends Model {
    public function products(){
        return $this->hasMany(Product::class);
    }
}
```

I presume each `Product` has an attribute `feature_id` which hold the id of the `Feature` to which it's belongsTo.

```
$products = Product::with([’features’])->where(category_id, $category_id)->get(); // This query will return list of product

foreach($products as $product){
    // You can access $feature of product like this
    $feature = $product->feature;
}
```

Because I have already define the reverse relation between the both Model I can access Product from Feature as well.

```
$feature->products(); // This will return a collection of Product and I can perform any sort of query on that too

// Like count number of Products
$feature->products()->count();
$feature->products()->first(); // get the first product
$feature->products()->last(); // get the last product
```

And so on and so fourth

Comment: They have been defined, and i also have productFeature model. the collection of products has been filtered by category and also some features too, so the productFeature model seems doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have `products` relationship on the `Feature` model you can try this!

```
$features = Feature::withCount(['products' => function($query){
   $query->where('category_id', $category_id);
}])->get();
```

You will have a `products_count` with each record of the collection.

Comment: The category_id belongs to products, not from feature, so where clause doesn't work